# neighboring elements in totally order set

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I am reading the article “ Free $\sigma $Products and Noncommutatively Slender Groups” written by KATSUYA EDA, and I fond that he used term neighboring elements, what is the definition of neighboring elements $\alpha , \beta$ in totally order set.